# Password reset view, email is not sending

Tags: python, django, email

after resetting password Im instantly redirecting to the password_reset/done view and im not receiving the email. I send email manually to chceck if its working and everything is ok, so the problem is with the
" path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('profile:password_reset_done')), name='password_reset'), ", Is this problem with the app_name or something, I cant find any working solution to this

```
from django.urls import path, reverse_lazy
from .views import ProfileDetail, FollowUser, RegisterUser
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth_views

app_name = 'profile'

urlpatterns = [
    path('<slug:slug>/profile/', ProfileDetail.as_view(), name='profile-details'),
    path('follow/', FollowUser.as_view(), name='follow'),
    path('register/', RegisterUser.as_view(), name='register'),
    path('login/', auth_views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='registration/login.html'), name='login'),
    path('logout/', auth_views.LogoutView.as_view(), name='logout'),

    path('password_reset/', auth_views.PasswordResetView.as_view(success_url=reverse_lazy('profile:password_reset_done')), name='password_reset'),
    path('password_reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
    path('reset/<uidb64>/<token>/', auth_views.PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
    path('reset/done/', auth_views.PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),

    path('password_change/', auth_views.PasswordChangeView.as_view(), name='password_change'),
    path('password_change/done/', auth_views.PasswordChangeDoneView.as_view(), name='password_change_done'),
]
```

main urls:

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('post.urls', namespace='post')),
    path('profile/', include('user_profile.urls', namespace='profile')),
]

if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
    urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

settings config:

```
EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.smtp.EmailBackend'
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.gmail.com'
EMAIL_PORT = '587'
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
EMAIL_HOST_USER = ***
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ***
DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL = EMAIL_HOST_USER
```

Comment: Are you able to send an email to the same user from within the django context? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/email/

Comment: Yeah, I sended a test email from shell and I received it normally

Comment: Do you see the email in your console if you set `EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'`?

Comment: No, I dont see anything, its instantly redirecting to the 'password_reset_done' url normally it takes like 3-5 secs before redirecting and this time its instant

Comment: I can't comment yet, Have you tried to set allow less secure apps in your Gmail settings and check if it's in the spams

Comment: Yes, I sent mail from the shell, everything is ok, I think theres some problem with PasswordResetView and app_name